# read file from assets android

Tags: android, io

I'm trying to build a card viewer in android for a trading card game. My plan was to use an arraylist to populate the cards into the database. I would read in all values from file and would be displayed via listview. My listview code and arraylist code is fine (after testing without using file input). The problem occurs when I attempt to read in from file. I'm at a loss of what to do. When I run the program like this, it crashes. When I remove the "parseInt" method (because i'm reading in an integer from file), it runs, but none of my data is populated. What is wrong with my io code?

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.io.*;

    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;


    public class DeckBuilderActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_deck_builder);

    //populate       database************************************************************************
    ArrayList<Card> database = new ArrayList<Card>(); //create new arraylist of datatype card

    //value holders
    String cardName, expansion, cardNum, unitType, unitClan, unitRace, trigger, unitSkill, cardLore,
            imageId;
    int unitGrade, unitPower, unitShield;
    //exception handling

    try{
        String myfile = "cardmaindatabase.txt";
        InputStream inputReader = getAssets().open(myfile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputReader)); //open file
        //begin populating with a for loop
        int i = 0; //incrementer
        while(reader.readLine() != null) //while not end of file
        {
            //assign values to placeholders

            //add new card and take parameters
            database.add(new Card());
            database.get(i).setCardName(reader.readLine());
            database.get(i).setExpansion(reader.readLine());
            database.get(i).setCardNum(reader.readLine());
            database.get(i).setUnitGrade(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));





        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //******************************************************************************************
    //populate arraylist
    ArrayAdapter<Card> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, database);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.card_database_listview);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Comment: What error do you see in the logcat when your app crashes?

Comment: it's wierd. It says it encountered a fatal exception while reading in a value. Calls it an invalid integer. I'm not sure how it's reading that data as an integer when i'm intending it to be read as a string.

Comment: Maybe your file isn't in the Assets folder. Are you sure your file is inside the src/main/assets/ folder?

Comment: I'm going to revisit my code with a fine-tooth comb. maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        try {

            InputStream is = mContext.getResources().getAssets().open("your-file-path");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //play with each line here 
            }
}...
```

Try this code to get data from the assets.

OR if you don't want to clear your code. try modify your code like this. I think the problem is in your loop.

```
String line = null;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) //while not end of file
        {
            //play with each line here

        }
```

**but collecting/storing data like this is unstable and hard to maintain. i'll suggest to use JSON. to store data in asset,so you could be able to collect and store data as fast as possible.**